# Generating Daily and Monthly sales Report

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

Good day guys,

I have a table in `SQLSERVER 2016` named `TblOrder_Details`, I want to generate daily report to show `Qty, Price, Amount` and also have a summary of the Total_amount sales in the day, and this should show other days within the range of days selected

The code below is what I have tried but I keep getting issues when I use the `SUM()` aggregate function as it does allow only grouping with one column

```
SELECT item_Name,qty, price, amount, Sum(amount) as Total_Amount 
FROM     tblOrderDetails  
where  Order_Date between @startdate and @enddate  GROUP BY Order_Date
```

I am getting this report into a Crystal Report, But it does not display the result. I have tried using `GROUP BY` all Columns I selected, not rendering the way I want.

OUTPUT should be in form of

```
OrderDate: 2019/07/29
item_Name   qty   price    amount
rice         2     2,000    4,000
beans        4     4,000    16,000


Summary
Total_qty=2
Total_AMount = 20,000

Order_Date:  2019/07/30
item_Name   qty   price    amount
soap         2     2,500    5,000
slippers     4     3,000    12,000


Summary
Total_qty=2
Total_Amount = 17,000
```

Also if possible if I can generate for monthly sales and year sales too especially the report rendering in crystal

Please help guys

Comment: For the `Amount`, calculate the `qty * price`. Why are you using `SUM(Amount)`?

Comment: sum(Amount) As Total_Amount, this is to calculate the total Sum of goods sold in the day

Comment: for the qty*price, I have the Amount calculated and saved already

Comment: You should be able to do all of your calculations in the Crystal Report. Create running values for your `Total Amounts` and `Total Quantity`

Comment: Adding onto WEI_DBA's comment, SQL Server will not return results in the way you show in your OUTPUT section above. You may have more luck posting this with the [crystal-reports] tag.

Comment: thank you @FembotDBA. 
I just did that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired output you can use this query (for daily report):

```
SELECT  item_Name ,
        qty ,
        price ,
        amount ,
        Total_Amount,
        Order_Date 
FROM    tblOrderDetails T
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT SUM(amount) AS Total_Amount ,
                            Order_Date
                     FROM   tblOrderDetails
                     WHERE  Order_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                     GROUP BY Order_Date
                   ) D ON D.Order_Date = T.Order_Date
WHERE   Order_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, what this does is to get the total of the goods bought and the price whereas what I want is get daily breakdown of each order details and now get the total_sales